# Penalty for medical malpractice in Dubai

Tags: criminal-law, uae

I’m pursuing a career in a specific medical career and I’d love to one day be able to move to Dubai, but I’m a bit discouraged by the fact that doctors can potentially end up in jail for medical malpractice or medical negligence.

If the worst happens, how many years would a doctor go to jail for a mistake he/she made or for negligence? Is there any way to check this online? Are there any official governmental websites that include laws regarding this matter?

Answer (score 1):

There are, sort of. You may be able to get the information you want [here](https://www.dha.gov.ae/Asset%20Library/MarketingAssets/20180611/(E)%20Federal%20Decree%20no.%204%20of%202016.pdf), but it is possible that the document will never download completely. Article 34 is the main item of concern, being the one governing imprisonment, which says:

> Whoever is proven to commit a  gross medical error as set out herein
>   shall be sentenced to not more than one year-imprisonment and shall be
>   fined two hundred thousand AED, or to either of these two penalties.
>   If the gross medical error causes a death of a  person, the
>   perpetrator shall be sentenced to not more than two year-imprisonment
>   and shall be fined not more than five hundred thousand AED, or to
>   either of these two penalties. If the crime provided in the first
>   Paragraph of this Article is committed under influence of alcohol or
>   the drugs, then the perpetrator shall be sentenced to not more than
>   Two year-imprisonment and shall  be fined not more than a million AED.

[This site](https://www.tamimi.com/law-update-articles/the-new-cabinet-resolution-no-40-of-2019-concerning-the-uae-federal-law-on-medical-liability-law-no-4-of-2016-an-analysis/) references some cabinet clarifications, which do not appear to correspond to anything yet online. Dubai Health Authority does not make regulations easily available, so you may need to request an account to get information.